# How to compare NSError.code to #defined error number in Swift 5

Tags: objective-c, swift, nserror

I have been working with Objective-C for a couple of years know but I am still quite new to Swift.

Currently I am working to add some new Swift 5 based code to an existing Objective-C project which uses defined constants for error codes and `NSError` objects to propagate errors.

How can I use `NSError.code` in Swift?

Obective-C code:

```
#define someStrangeError_Code   1000
typedef void(^CompletionHandler)(BOOL success, NSError *error);

...

- (void)doSomethingAsync:(CompletionHandler)completion {
    // ... do something

    if (errorOccured) {
        completion(false, [NSError errorWithDomain:@"MyErrorDomain" code:someStrangeError_Code userInfo:nil])
    } else {
        completion(true, nil)
    }

    ...
}    

[someObjc doSomethingAsync:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    if (error != nil && error.code == someStrangeError_Code) {
        ....
    }
}];
```

Swift code:

```
someObjc.doSomethingAsync(completion: { (success, error) in 
    if ((error as NSError?)?.code == someStrangeError_Code) {
        // ERROR
        // Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int?' and 'Int32'
    }
})
```

I know that Swift uses the `Error` protocol instead of `NSError`. However, `NSError` complies to `Error` and thus using `NSError` should not be a problem, should it?

Comparing a simple error code to a constant should not be that hard, but I could not solve this.

So what is the correct "Swift way" to check the error code an to avoid

> Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int?' and 'Int32'

Comment: Is the callback always called with some error, even if no error occurred?

Comment: If no error occured the closure is called with `error = nil`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C integers are imported to Swift as `Int32`, and that cannot be compared to an optional `Int?` directly. A conversion helps:

```
if ((error as NSError?)?.code == Int(someStrangeError_Code)) {
    // some strange error
}
```

Alternatively, unwrap the optional error first:

```
if let error = error {
    if (error as NSError).code == someStrangeError_Code {
        // some strange error
    } else {
        // some other error
    }
} else {
    // no error
}
```

Yet another option is to change the (Objective-)C definition to

```
#define someStrangeError_Code   1000L
```

for a `long int` constant, which is imported to Swift as `Int`. Then your original Swift code would compile again.

Comment: Shouldn't `as NSError?` be `as? NSError` ?

Comment: @rmaddy: You can always cast `Error` to `NSError`, and therefore `Error?` to `NSError?` . But it probably would not make a difference.

Comment: @rmaddy:  `error as? NSError` gives a compiler warning “Conditional downcast from 'Error?' to 'NSError' is a bridging conversion; did you mean to use 'as'?” with the fix-it “Replace 'as? NSError' with 'as NSError?'”